# Cross site form post with external site on different domain

Tags: security

We're intergrating our site with an external site using form posts. The form on our page will submit to extenal site on a different domain. Is this even possible? I thought that would be an injection attack.

Comment: It's not injection unless the external site has forgotten to escape incoming data. It might be possible to do cross-site-request-forgery attacks on the external site through form submissions, if that site has no XSRF protection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it should be possible. Make sure you have enough validations in place so that you dont post harmfull data (and you are not held responsible) also I hope the other party has some server side validation as well.

Answer (score 0):

There is a type of vulnerability is called Cross Site Request Forgeries or XSRF.  XSRF has nothing to do with the type of data,  but rather that the request originates from a different server. 
http://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSRF

Here is an XSRF exploit POST request that I wrote:
http://www.exploit-db.com/exploits/7922/
This javascript is used to automatically fire off a form when the page is viewed:

```
<script>document.getElementById(1).submit();</script>
```

Comment: The milw0rm link is dead :(

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to learn more about the same-origin policy, this is the best writeup I have found: http://code.google.com/p/browsersec/wiki/Part2#Same-origin_policy