# asp.net do a postback on page load

Tags: asp.net, forms, post

how do i code an aspx.page that does a post to an external site on page load?

Example:

```
<form action="https://demo.demopage.net/" method="post">
   <input type="hidden" name="lang" value="de" />
</form>
```

My intention is to open `opener.aspx` in a `target=_blank`. Opener.aspx will do a `postback` to the above form.

thx for your help...

Comment: Please provide some more details.

Comment: I dont think you need opener.aspx just use the code you posted in the page that has the link. Try avoiding target=_blank as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a "postback" so much as it is a standard HTTP POST request.  ASP.NET probably isn't necessary.  How about something like this (using jQuery)...

```
<form id="someForm" action="https://demo.demopage.net/" method="post">
  ...
</form>
```

and

```
$(document)ready(function() {
  $('#someForm').submit();
});
```

Comment: @VikciaR: I'm not sure, actually.  It definitely won't work as an AJAX request because of the same origin policy, but a standard POST might work.  It's worth a try.  POST is, after all, a normal restful request.

Comment: But you can post for example password change (if user is logged in some third party web site and with cookie session token)... So it's why I doubt that this will work...

Comment: This post is about it. So, it possible, but must be tryed: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1587815/cross-site-form-post-with-external-site-on-different-domain <script>document.getElementById(1).submit();</script>

Answer (score 0):

You can use server side http post: [HttpWebRequest, HttpWebResponse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)